# Weak references and method arrayWithObject of NSArray

Tags: objective-c

```
@autoreleasepool {
    __weak NSArray* obj1 = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[ClassA alloc] init]];
    NSLog(@"%@", obj1);

    __weak NSArray* obj2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[ClassA alloc] init], nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", obj2);
}
```

For obj2 the result is "null", that's right, but for obj1 the result is "ClassA: 0x100109b40". I don't understand, why?

Comment: Try compiling with optimizations turned on.  Then try again across different OS releases (including betas).   You'll likely see a difference in behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is down to autorelease semantics. The reference `obj1` is returned autoreleased, and so is "owned" by the autorelease pool (i.e. the pool has a strong reference to it). It will thus survive until the pool drains, as the weak reference is not the only reference to the object.

The second object is not "owned" by anything other than the weak reference. Therefore, the compiler will infer it can be released immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) `obj2` is released right after creating it since there's only a weak reference held to it. In ARC, an object keeps living as long as there's a strong pointer to it. Since you're creating a weak pointer, the object is deallocated immediately.
`obj1` however is autoreleased. This means the object will keep living until the autorelease pool is drained. In ARC terms: the autorelease pool holds a strong reference to it. Since the autorelease pool is not drained yet by the time `NSLog(@"%@", obj1);` is called, you can still access and use the object.

You might want to read these docs to learn more about the differences between automatic and manual reference counting:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html